# Vernacula and Vernacu

Tags: discussion, tags

I notice that two tags have appeared, vernacu and vernacula. Are these words that I don't understand or typos for vernacular? If the latter, what should I do about it?

Comment: probably misspellings/typos for *vernacular* (as is yours?)

Comment: @Mari-LouA, well spotted. Should I do anything about it?

Comment: Correct the spelling on the tags? Is there a tag for "vernacular"? Maybe you could change the tag to *slang* or *colloquial*.

Answer (score 8):

[Tags are automatically deleted within a short amount if time if they have no posts.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags) So the proper way to deal with misspelled tags that cover a small number of questions is to re-tag. In this case, neither of the tags have posts associated with them, so these tags should disappear soon.

If the misspelling is particularly common and recurrent, it may be worth merging with the proper spelling.

Edit:
As of 16 Jan 2016, [vernacu](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vernacu) and [vernacula](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vernacula) seem to be "destroyed."